# CopyPicture Range Name after other cell

Tags: vba

I'm trying to CopyPicture cells in Column B, and name them the value in Column 1.  I have code that works, except it keeps giving the pictures the wrong names.  The baffling thing is that sometimes it works perfectly, and other times it does not.

I have tried to cobble together a routine based on posted examples of the CopyPicture command.  I'm pasting it in below.

Yes, I'm a newbie at VBScript.  Be gentle. ;-)

```
Sub makepic()
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\BP\BP2020\JPGs\"
    Dim CLen As Integer
    Dim cntr As Integer
    cntr = 1
    Dim rgExp As Range
    Dim CCntr As String
    CString2 = "A1:A6"
    Set rgExp2 = Range(CString2)
    CString = "B1:B6"
    Set rgExp = Range(CString)

    For I = 1 To rgExp.Cells.Count Step 1
      CCntr = rgExp2.Cells(I).Value
      rgExp.Cells.Cells(I).Font.Size = 72
      rgExp.Cells.Cells(I).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
      rgExp.Cells.Cells(I).Font.Size = 14
      ''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
      CLen = Len(rgExp.Cells.Cells(I).Value)
      CWidth = CLen * 85

      With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=1600, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
        Width:=CWidth, Height:=50)
        .Name = "ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT"
        .Activate
      End With

      ''' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete chart.
      If CCntr <> "" Then
        ActiveChart.Paste

        Selection.Name = "pastedPic"

        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT").Chart.Export (path + CCntr & ".jpg")
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT").Delete
      End If
      cntr = cntr + 1
   Next
End Sub
```

Again, I expect -- for example -- a picture of the contents of cell B1 to have the name of the contents of A1.  I tried making the range A1:B4 (for example), but that got me 8 pictures.  I finally decided to try to make 2 ranges, but that didn't work either.

Comment: `and other times it does not` - so what happens then?

Comment: It copies the pictures, but the names don't match the corresponding pictures.